# Implements in a Property definition

Tags: c#, vb.net

So I am trying to convert some VB code to C#.  The property definition goes like this:

```
Public Overridable ReadOnly Property [Error]() As String Implements System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Error
```

The conversion that I have seen makes it look like this:

```
public virtual string Error
```

Now I understand everything here except that it ignores the Implements line.  Is this just not necessary in C#?

Comment: This just further exemplifies why I loathe VB syntax ;)

Comment: @EvanL Actually that's something I like about VB.net syntax, it is very explicit and readable. The comparable C# is just less characters, but when you think about it, if you understanding the idea of overriding in OO, the word 'overrides' says a lot more than 'virtual'. Then the thing you're describing isn't a string, it's a function that returns a string. The only way to know that is to know the language. Then the way of calling it an error in VB requires escaping the keyword, reminding you that that's what is happening.

Comment: @JCollins I understand the allure to VB.Net syntax and that it is so verbose for a *reason*.  It's just my personal opinion really, and from coding in C# for a long time, seeing the keyword `virtual` prompts me to the same things the VB example does.  I do understand why *other developers* who may look at the code would probably benefit from the overall verbosity of VB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this just not necessary in C#?

No - C# will implicitly implement an interface by default.  *Normally* you can explicitly implement an interface method:

```
string System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Error
```

but in your case the property is `virtual` so you can't use explicit implementation (explicit implementations must be `private` which makes no sense for `virtual` members).

The main difference in implicit and explicit implementation is that a consumer will need to have a reference of the interface type, or cast the class to the interface:

```
MyDataErrorInfo impl = new MyDataErrorInfo();
string s;
IDataErrorInfo i = new MyDataErrorInfo();   // implicitly cast 

s = i.Error;  // works
s = ((IDataErrorInfo)impl).Error;  // works
s = impl.Error;   // does not work
```

Comment: [_"It is a compile-time error for an explicit interface member implementation to include access modifiers"_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(v=vs.71).aspx). Lose the `public`. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard `readonly` is for _fields_ - for a readonly _property_ you would just implement a private `set` accessor.

Comment: @CodeCaster not only that, but it can't be _virtual_ either since a virtual private method makes no sense.

Comment: Gah - I edit my comment incorrectly and now can't fix it :(  You can't use a private `set` accessor on an explicit interface implementation - you have to _not_ implement a set accessor (which means you can't use automatic properties)

Answer (score 1):

A property implementation of an interface in C# doesn't need to mention the interface:

```
public virtual string Error { get; set; }
```

If you want an explicit interface implementation:

```
string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get; set; }
```

Comment: So does the 2nd one there relate to a Private in VB then?

Comment: @j5juice see [13.4.1 Explicit interface member implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(v=vs.71).aspx): _"Because explicit interface member implementations are never accessible through their fully qualified name in a method invocation or a property access, they are in a sense private. However, since they can be accessed through an interface instance, they are in a sense also public"_. If explicitly implemented, you can't access `((YourImplementation)yourInstance).Error` as in that sense it is private, but you _can_ through `((IDataErrorInfo)yourInstance).Error`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the property as readonly, then you need to use non-automatic properties (VB also forbids an automatic property implementing a readonly property):

Implicit implementation:

```
public string Error
{
    get
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Explicit implementation:

```
string System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Error
{
    get
    {
        //...
    }
}
```